# Somebody help me understand this ctypes python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

```
hotkey_ = enable_shortcut       # Check to break the while loop

def proper_fctn():
    if hotkey_:
        if not user32.RegisterHotKey(None, shortcut_id, modifier, vk):
            pass
        try:
            msg = wintypes.MSG()
            while user32.GetMessageA(byref(msg), None, 0, 0) != 0:
                if msg.message == win32con.WM_HOTKEY:
                    if not hotkey_:
                        break
                    fctn_to_run()
                user32.TranslateMessage(byref(msg))
                user32.DispatchMessageA(byref(msg))
        except:
            pass
```

If somebody could help me understand the lines, so I could understand the process better.

Comment: That's like...all the lines. Can you be more specific about your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Win32 APIs.  All of them are well-documented in Microsoft's MSDN documentation.  You've basically written a Windows application with a standard main loop.

Google takes you straight to their docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage